# How to make the resize property work with flexBox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, resize

I would like to know how to use (if possible) Flexboxes and the resize property together. Consider the following code:

```html
 <div style='height:300px; background:black; display:flex;flex-direction:column'>
      <div style='resize:vertical; background:blue; flex-grow:1; height:100px; overflow:hidden'>
      </div>
 </div>
```

The resize does not work – I would like to know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `flex-grow` or on each resize you will trigger the grow to have again a full height element. Use `height:100%` instead:

```html
<div style='height:300px; background:black; display:flex;flex-direction:column'>
  <div style='resize:vertical; background:blue; ; height:100%; overflow:hidden'>
  </div>
</div>
```

To better illustrate the issue consider 2 elements and see how on the resize you will have a weird jump:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.container> :first-child {
  resize: vertical;
  background: blue;
  flex-grow:5;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container> :last-child {
  background: red;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div >
  </div>
  <div >
  </div>
</div>
```